# Print out items from a list in R with different nested levels

Tags: r, list, for-loop, purrr

I have a list in R with the structure as in the dput output.

## Update:

```
structure(list(name = c("\\text{Students are able to identify relationship between l (or ml) and cm³\n}", 
"\\text{Students are able to write down the notation and representations of fractions \n}", 
"\\text{Scientific enquiry}", "\\text{Polska w okresie rozbicia dzielnicowego.}"
), index = c(26L, 39L, 0L, 5L), learningFactorType = c("LEARNING_OBJECTIVE", 
"LEARNING_OBJECTIVE", "LEARNING_OBJECTIVE", "LEARNING_OBJECTIVE"
), childFactors = list(structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(`_id` = list(structure(as.raw(c(0xee, 0x41, 
    0x32, 0x09, 0x81, 0x82, 0xf4, 0xac, 0x27, 0x49, 0xc2, 0x0b, 
    0x70, 0x65, 0x05, 0x89)), type = as.raw(0x03)), structure(as.raw(c(0xdc, 
    0x46, 0xaf, 0x85, 0x60, 0x2b, 0x6a, 0x04, 0x15, 0x48, 0x7c, 
    0xa5, 0xd0, 0xbc, 0x27, 0x8b)), type = as.raw(0x03)), structure(as.raw(c(0x76, 
    0x4a, 0x90, 0xc0, 0x90, 0xc6, 0xf1, 0x76, 0x18, 0x51, 0x13, 
    0xc1, 0xae, 0xa1, 0x03, 0x84)), type = as.raw(0x03)), structure(as.raw(c(0xec, 
    0x42, 0x98, 0x7a, 0xd4, 0x16, 0x23, 0x3f, 0x43, 0xfd, 0x36, 
    0x5d, 0xa1, 0x4a, 0xcd, 0xa8)), type = as.raw(0x03))), name = c("\\text{ Ideas and evidence}", 
    "\\text{Plan investigative work}", "\\text{Obtain and present evidence}", 
    "\\text{ Consider evidence and approach}"), index = 0:3, 
        childFactors = list(structure(list(`_id` = list(structure(as.raw(c(0xee, 
        0x49, 0x92, 0x4f, 0xe2, 0x10, 0xb8, 0x33, 0x6f, 0xbe, 
        0xd2, 0x9f, 0x46, 0x82, 0x36, 0x9d)), type = as.raw(0x03)), 
            structure(as.raw(c(0xa2, 0x4e, 0x9c, 0x07, 0x44, 
            0x1b, 0x7b, 0x44, 0xa3, 0x03, 0xe9, 0x22, 0x69, 0xaf, 
            0x5b, 0x85)), type = as.raw(0x03))), name = c("\\text{Collect evidence in a variety of contexts (4Ep1)}", 
        "\\text{Test an idea or prediction based on scientific knowledge and understanding (4Ep2)}"
        ), index = 0:1, childFactors = list(list(), list()), 
            exerciseIdList = list(list(), list()), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(
                list(), list()), linkedSourceList = list(structure(list(
                publisherId = c(193, 193, 193, 193, 193, 193), 
                categoryId = c(22610, 22610, 22610, 22612, 22614, 
                22614), levelId = c(1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 
                1001), subcategoryIdList = list(22618, 22619, 
                  22620, 22628, 22631, 22634), exerciseIdList = list(
                  c(281313, 281322, 281439, 281442), c(281310, 
                  281312, 281437), c(281307, 281324), c(325294, 
                  325296, 325380, 325394, 325448, 325473, 325516
                  ), c(328850, 328851, 328853, 328856, 328861, 
                  328869, 328870, 328871), c(328854, 335329)), 
                knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(list(), list(), 
                  list(), list(), list(), list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
            6L)), structure(list(publisherId = c(193, 193), categoryId = c(22614, 
            22614), levelId = c(1001, 1001), subcategoryIdList = list(
                22632, 22633), exerciseIdList = list(c(328852, 
            335327), c(328865, 335324)), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(
                list(), list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2))), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2), 
            structure(list(`_id` = list(structure(as.raw(c(0x43, 
            0x46, 0xbd, 0xa0, 0x8f, 0xf6, 0x37, 0xad, 0x48, 0x37, 
            0xeb, 0x2f, 0x6f, 0xfe, 0x34, 0xb4)), type = as.raw(0x03)), 
                structure(as.raw(c(0xca, 0x4b, 0x33, 0x04, 0x0b, 
                0x2f, 0x1d, 0x75, 0xc6, 0x84, 0xaa, 0xff, 0xfb, 
                0x4c, 0x95, 0xa8)), type = as.raw(0x03)), structure(as.raw(c(0xcc, 
                0x45, 0xa4, 0xec, 0x0a, 0xb1, 0x5a, 0x02, 0x29, 
                0xf2, 0x58, 0x21, 0x58, 0x29, 0xab, 0x8a)), type = as.raw(0x03))), 
                name = c("\\text{Suggest questions that can be tested and make predictions; \ncommunicate these (4Ep3)}", 
                "\\text{Design a fair test and plan how to collect sufficient evidence (4Ep4)}", 
                "\\text{Choose apparatus and decide what to measure (4Ep5)}"
                ), index = 0:2, childFactors = list(list(), list(), 
                  list()), exerciseIdList = list(list(), list(), 
                  list()), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(list(), 
                  list(), list()), linkedSourceList = list(structure(list(
                  publisherId = c(193, 193, 193, 193), categoryId = c(22611, 
                  22611, 22615, 22615), levelId = c(1001, 1001, 
                  1001, 1001), subcategoryIdList = list(22624, 
                    22625, 22635, 22637), exerciseIdList = list(
                    c(325414, 325415, 325420, 325433), c(325416, 
                    325417, 325418, 325419, 325423, 325427, 325430, 
                    325434, 334617, 334647, 334658), c(328887, 
                    328891), c(328895, 328898, 328904)), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(
                    list(), list(), list(), list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                4L)), structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"), 
                  structure(list(publisherId = 193, categoryId = 22611, 
                    levelId = 1001, subcategoryIdList = list(
                      22625), exerciseIdList = list(c(325416, 
                    325417, 325418, 325419, 325423, 325427, 325430, 
                    325434, 334617, 334647, 334658)), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(
                      list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
            3L)), structure(list(`_id` = list(structure(as.raw(c(0xf1, 
            0x41, 0xd0, 0xff, 0x4c, 0xaf, 0x1a, 0x7c, 0x8f, 0x4e, 
            0x8a, 0xdb, 0xdb, 0xd2, 0x87, 0xa7)), type = as.raw(0x03)), 
                structure(as.raw(c(0x7f, 0x42, 0xce, 0xf2, 0x3f, 
                0xe4, 0xc3, 0x9f, 0xb7, 0x17, 0x52, 0xfe, 0xb3, 
                0x8a, 0xc9, 0x89)), type = as.raw(0x03)), structure(as.raw(c(0x77, 
                0x49, 0xcc, 0x51, 0xb0, 0x85, 0x03, 0xf5, 0x72, 
                0xeb, 0x2f, 0xe5, 0x6e, 0x32, 0x53, 0x8b)), type = as.raw(0x03)), 
                structure(as.raw(c(0xe1, 0x40, 0x24, 0xb9, 0x1e, 
                0x32, 0xbe, 0xca, 0x33, 0x5e, 0x9e, 0x3d, 0xd0, 
                0x2f, 0x1a, 0x87)), type = as.raw(0x03))), name = c("\\text{Make relevant observations and comparisons in a variety of \ncontexts (4Eo1)}", 
            "\\text{Measure temperature, time, force and length (4Eo2)}", 
            "\\text{Begin to think about the need for repeated measurements of, \nfor example, length (4Eo3)}", 
            "\\text{Present results in drawings, bar charts and tables (4Eo4)}"
            ), index = 0:3, childFactors = list(list(), list(), 
                list(), list()), exerciseIdList = list(list(), 
                list(), list(), list()), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(
                list(), list(), list(), list()), linkedSourceList = list(
                structure(list(publisherId = c(193, 193, 193, 
                193, 193), categoryId = c(22610, 22610, 22610, 
                22612, 22614), levelId = c(1001, 1001, 1001, 
                1001, 1001), subcategoryIdList = list(22619, 
                  22620, 22621, 22628, 22631), exerciseIdList = list(
                  c(281310, 281312, 281437), c(281307, 281324
                  ), c(281308, 281326), c(325294, 325296, 325380, 
                  325394, 325448, 325473, 325516), c(328850, 
                  328851, 328853, 328856, 328861, 328869, 328870, 
                  328871)), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(list(), 
                  list(), list(), list(), list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                5L)), structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"), 
                structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"), 
                structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
            4L)), structure(list(`_id` = list(structure(as.raw(c(0xc1, 
            0x41, 0x64, 0x24, 0x4d, 0x96, 0x1d, 0xc5, 0x4b, 0x18, 
            0x9f, 0xc3, 0xe2, 0xfe, 0x82, 0xb9)), type = as.raw(0x03)), 
                structure(as.raw(c(0x8a, 0x44, 0x8a, 0x41, 0xed, 
                0x1d, 0x70, 0xdc, 0x81, 0x96, 0x29, 0x0a, 0x49, 
                0xe8, 0x73, 0xa3)), type = as.raw(0x03)), structure(as.raw(c(0x9d, 
                0x4a, 0x23, 0x7c, 0x2a, 0x57, 0x55, 0x31, 0xca, 
                0xd4, 0x17, 0xff, 0x32, 0x9b, 0xfa, 0x9c)), type = as.raw(0x03))), 
                name = c("\\text{Identify simple trends and patterns in results and suggest \nexplanations for some of these (4Eo5)}", 
                "\\text{Explain what the evidence shows and whether it supports \npredictions.  Communicate this clearly to others (4Eo6)}", 
                "\\text{Link evidence to scientific knowledge and understanding in \nsome contexts (4Eo7)}"
                ), index = 0:2, childFactors = list(list(), list(), 
                  list()), exerciseIdList = list(list(), list(), 
                  list()), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(list(), 
                  list(), list()), linkedSourceList = list(structure(list(
                  publisherId = c(193, 193, 193, 193), categoryId = c(22611, 
                  22614, 22614, 22615), levelId = c(1001, 1001, 
                  1001, 1001), subcategoryIdList = list(22625, 
                    22632, 22633, 22636), exerciseIdList = list(
                    c(325416, 325417, 325418, 325419, 325423, 
                    325427, 325430, 325434, 334617, 334647, 334658
                    ), c(328852, 335327), c(328865, 335324), 
                    c(328886, 328888, 328903)), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(
                    list(), list(), list(), list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                4L)), structure(list(publisherId = 193, categoryId = 22615, 
                  levelId = 1001, subcategoryIdList = list(22637), 
                  exerciseIdList = list(c(328895, 328898, 328904
                  )), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
                  structure(list(publisherId = c(193, 193, 193
                  ), categoryId = c(22612, 22614, 22614), levelId = c(1001, 
                  1001, 1001), subcategoryIdList = list(22628, 
                    22633, 22634), exerciseIdList = list(c(325294, 
                  325296, 325380, 325394, 325448, 325473, 325516
                  ), c(328865, 335324), c(328854, 335329)), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(
                    list(), list(), list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                  3L)))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
            3L))), exerciseIdList = list(list(), list(), list(), 
            list()), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(list(), 
            list(), list(), list()), linkedSourceList = list(
            structure(list(publisherId = c(193, 193, 193, 193, 
            193, 193, 193, 193), categoryId = c(22610, 22610, 
            22610, 22612, 22614, 22614, 22614, 22614), levelId = c(1001, 
            1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001), subcategoryIdList = list(
                22618, 22619, 22620, 22628, 22631, 22634, 22632, 
                22633), exerciseIdList = list(c(281313, 281322, 
            281439, 281442), c(281310, 281312, 281437), c(281307, 
            281324), c(325294, 325296, 325380, 325394, 325448, 
            325473, 325516), c(328850, 328851, 328853, 328856, 
            328861, 328869, 328870, 328871), c(328854, 335329
            ), c(328852, 335327), c(328865, 335324)), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(
                list(), list(), list(), list(), list(), list(), 
                list(), list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
            8L)), structure(list(publisherId = c(193, 193, 193, 
            193, 193), categoryId = c(22611, 22611, 22615, 22615, 
            22611), levelId = c(1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001), 
                subcategoryIdList = list(22624, 22625, 22635, 
                  22637, 22625), exerciseIdList = list(c(325414, 
                325415, 325420, 325433), c(325416, 325417, 325418, 
                325419, 325423, 325427, 325430, 325434, 334617, 
                334647, 334658), c(328887, 328891), c(328895, 
                328898, 328904), c(325416, 325417, 325418, 325419, 
                325423, 325427, 325430, 325434, 334617, 334647, 
                334658)), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(list(), 
                  list(), list(), list(), list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
            5L)), structure(list(publisherId = c(193, 193, 193, 
            193, 193), categoryId = c(22610, 22610, 22610, 22612, 
            22614), levelId = c(1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001), 
                subcategoryIdList = list(22619, 22620, 22621, 
                  22628, 22631), exerciseIdList = list(c(281310, 
                281312, 281437), c(281307, 281324), c(281308, 
                281326), c(325294, 325296, 325380, 325394, 325448, 
                325473, 325516), c(328850, 328851, 328853, 328856, 
                328861, 328869, 328870, 328871)), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(
                  list(), list(), list(), list(), list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
            5L)), structure(list(publisherId = c(193, 193, 193, 
            193, 193, 193, 193, 193), categoryId = c(22611, 22614, 
            22614, 22615, 22615, 22612, 22614, 22614), levelId = c(1001, 
            1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001), subcategoryIdList = list(
                22625, 22632, 22633, 22636, 22637, 22628, 22633, 
                22634), exerciseIdList = list(c(325416, 325417, 
            325418, 325419, 325423, 325427, 325430, 325434, 334617, 
            334647, 334658), c(328852, 335327), c(328865, 335324
            ), c(328886, 328888, 328903), c(328895, 328898, 328904
            ), c(325294, 325296, 325380, 325394, 325448, 325473, 
            325516), c(328865, 335324), c(328854, 335329)), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(
                list(), list(), list(), list(), list(), list(), 
                list(), list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
            8L)))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 4L
    )), structure(list(`_id` = list(structure(as.raw(c(0x76, 
    0x4f, 0x14, 0xee, 0xb1, 0x19, 0x89, 0xcd, 0x04, 0xd3, 0x44, 
    0x33, 0xa9, 0x1a, 0x6a, 0xbc)), type = as.raw(0x03)), structure(as.raw(c(0x3d, 
    0x4d, 0x57, 0x27, 0x96, 0x1a, 0x86, 0xc0, 0xf4, 0x27, 0x5b, 
    0x2d, 0x19, 0x32, 0xd2, 0x86)), type = as.raw(0x03)), structure(as.raw(c(0x44, 
    0x47, 0xac, 0x85, 0x90, 0x69, 0x04, 0x27, 0x68, 0x4d, 0x12, 
    0x1a, 0x79, 0xfd, 0x76, 0xa6)), type = as.raw(0x03)), structure(as.raw(c(0x4f, 
    0x49, 0x90, 0xd5, 0x40, 0x9c, 0x66, 0xe5, 0x76, 0x22, 0x05, 
    0x7a, 0xaf, 0xd2, 0x95, 0xac)), type = as.raw(0x03)), structure(as.raw(c(0x8c, 
    0x45, 0xfa, 0x87, 0xc8, 0x74, 0x08, 0xaf, 0xba, 0x3e, 0xb1, 
    0x22, 0xb4, 0x91, 0xa0, 0xa1)), type = as.raw(0x03))), name = c("\\text{Umieszczanie w czasie i przestrzeni Polski okresu rozbicia dzielnicowego.}", 
    "\\text{Opisywanie przyczyn oraz wskazywanie skutków rozbicia dzielnicowego.}", 
    "\\text{Umieszczanie w czasie najważniejszych wydarzeń związanych z relacjami polsko-krzyżackimi oraz zagrożeniem najazdami tatarskimi w okresie rozbicia dzielnicowego.}", 
    "\\text{Opisywanie przemiany społecznej i gospodarczej, z uwzględnieniem ruchu osadniczego.}", 
    "\\text{Charakteryzowanie procesu zjednoczenia państwa polskiego na przełomie XIII i XIV wieku, wskazując na rolę władców piastowskich (ze szczególnym uwzględnieniem roli Władysława Łokietka) oraz Kościoła.}"
    ), index = 0:4, childFactors = list(list(), list(), list(), 
        list(), list()), exerciseIdList = list(list(), list(), 
        list(), list(), list()), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(
        list(), list(), list(), list(), list()), linkedSourceList = list(
        list(), list(), list(), list(), list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    5L))), exerciseIdList = list(list(), list(), list(), list()), 
    levelIdSet = list(462, 459, 1001, c(34, 857, 877)), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(
        list(), list(), list(), list()), subjectId = c(49, 49, 
    357, 9), linkedSourceList = list(structure(list(publisherId = 111, 
        categoryId = 42281, levelId = 462, subcategoryIdList = list(
            42284), exerciseIdList = list(c(495048, 495047, 495043, 
        495044, 495045, 495046, 495049, 495050)), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(
            list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        structure(list(publisherId = 111, categoryId = 41394, 
            levelId = 459, subcategoryIdList = list(41395), exerciseIdList = list(
                c(473272, 473270, 473269, 473262, 473261, 465453, 
                465452)), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        structure(list(publisherId = c(193, 193, 193, 193, 193, 
        193, 193, 193, 193, 193, 193, 193, 193, 193, 193, 193, 
        193, 193, 193, 193, 193, 193, 193, 193, 193, 193), categoryId = c(22610, 
        22610, 22610, 22612, 22614, 22614, 22614, 22614, 22611, 
        22611, 22615, 22615, 22611, 22610, 22610, 22610, 22612, 
        22614, 22611, 22614, 22614, 22615, 22615, 22612, 22614, 
        22614), levelId = c(1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 
        1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 
        1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 
        1001, 1001), subcategoryIdList = list(22618, 22619, 22620, 
            22628, 22631, 22634, 22632, 22633, 22624, 22625, 
            22635, 22637, 22625, 22619, 22620, 22621, 22628, 
            22631, 22625, 22632, 22633, 22636, 22637, 22628, 
            22633, 22634), exerciseIdList = list(c(281313, 281322, 
        281439, 281442), c(281310, 281312, 281437), c(281307, 
        281324), c(325294, 325296, 325380, 325394, 325448, 325473, 
        325516), c(328850, 328851, 328853, 328856, 328861, 328869, 
        328870, 328871), c(328854, 335329), c(328852, 335327), 
            c(328865, 335324), c(325414, 325415, 325420, 325433
            ), c(325416, 325417, 325418, 325419, 325423, 325427, 
            325430, 325434, 334617, 334647, 334658), c(328887, 
            328891), c(328895, 328898, 328904), c(325416, 325417, 
            325418, 325419, 325423, 325427, 325430, 325434, 334617, 
            334647, 334658), c(281310, 281312, 281437), c(281307, 
            281324), c(281308, 281326), c(325294, 325296, 325380, 
            325394, 325448, 325473, 325516), c(328850, 328851, 
            328853, 328856, 328861, 328869, 328870, 328871), 
            c(325416, 325417, 325418, 325419, 325423, 325427, 
            325430, 325434, 334617, 334647, 334658), c(328852, 
            335327), c(328865, 335324), c(328886, 328888, 328903
            ), c(328895, 328898, 328904), c(325294, 325296, 325380, 
            325394, 325448, 325473, 325516), c(328865, 335324
            ), c(328854, 335329)), knowledgeBaseEntryIdList = list(
            list(), list(), list(), list(), list(), list(), list(), 
            list(), list(), list(), list(), list(), list(), list(), 
            list(), list(), list(), list(), list(), list(), list(), 
            list(), list(), list(), list(), list())), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        26L)), structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame")), 
    treeId = list(structure(as.raw(c(0xa6, 0x48, 0x30, 0x23, 
    0xe1, 0xce, 0xc1, 0x0e, 0x4d, 0x56, 0xe0, 0xc6, 0x6d, 0x71, 
    0x51, 0x96)), type = as.raw(0x03)), structure(as.raw(c(0x27, 
    0x4d, 0xc2, 0xf7, 0xcc, 0xcb, 0x8b, 0x82, 0x2f, 0x20, 0x25, 
    0x72, 0x33, 0x14, 0xee, 0xb7)), type = as.raw(0x03)), structure(as.raw(c(0x7d, 
    0x49, 0x2a, 0xf1, 0x7f, 0xde, 0xff, 0x2a, 0x37, 0x11, 0x33, 
    0x09, 0xaa, 0xa4, 0xd9, 0x87)), type = as.raw(0x03)), structure(as.raw(c(0xbb, 
    0x46, 0x98, 0x1b, 0xa8, 0x19, 0xeb, 0x30, 0x1b, 0x35, 0xf6, 
    0x22, 0x0f, 0xb2, 0x4c, 0x99)), type = as.raw(0x03))), version = c(111, 
    123, 104, 224), indexAlias = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to print out every name li[[1]] of the sub-list as well as the fifth item sub-sub-list li[[9]][[5]] with the exercise_ids.

The `purrr` package allows me to simple grab the elements of li[[9]],but I am not sure, how to map the name li[[1]]in the related list above.

```
ex_id<-li[[9]]
df_ex_id <- as.data.frame(unlist(map(ex.id,5)))
```

I tried to use the for function:

```
name_exid <- for (i in li$name) {
print(li$name) + print(li$exerciseIdList[[1]])  
}
```

But I get an error message and failed miserably :(

The outcome I would like to achieve is that I have column A with the name and a column B with the ex.ids

Comment: I bet this was built out of JSON import! Technically, `li` is a `data.frame` (a special `list`)

Answer (score 0):

Consider base R's `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`) to iterate elementwise between your needed items to bind into list or a data frame. Also, `sapply` can help extract needed nested list across all data frames in `li[[9]]`.

```
extract_list <- Map(function(nm, id, ex) list(name=nm, index=id, excerciseIdList=ex),
                    li$name,
                    li$index,
                    sapply(li[[9]], `[[`, "exerciseIdList"), USE.NAMES=FALSE)

extract_list
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$name
# [1] "\\text{Students are able to identify relationship between l (or ml) and cm³\n}"
# 
# [[1]]$index
# [1] 26
# 
# [[1]]$excerciseIdList
# [1] 495048 495047 495043 495044 495045 495046 495049 495050
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]]$name
# [1] "\\text{Students are able to write down the notation and representations of fractions \n}"
# 
# [[2]]$index
# [1] 39
# 
# [[2]]$excerciseIdList
# [1] 473272 473270 473269 473262 473261 465453 465452
```

To build a data frame:

```
df_list <- Map(function(nm, id, ex) data.frame(name=nm, index=id, excerciseIdList=ex,
                                               stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
               li$name,
               li$index,
               sapply(li[[9]], `[[`, "exerciseIdList"))

final_df <- do.call(rbind, unname(df_list))

final_df    
#                                                                                        name index excerciseIdList
# 1            \\text{Students are able to identify relationship between l (or ml) and cm³\n}    26          495048
# 2            \\text{Students are able to identify relationship between l (or ml) and cm³\n}    26          495047
# 3            \\text{Students are able to identify relationship between l (or ml) and cm³\n}    26          495043
# 4            \\text{Students are able to identify relationship between l (or ml) and cm³\n}    26          495044
# 5            \\text{Students are able to identify relationship between l (or ml) and cm³\n}    26          495045
# 6            \\text{Students are able to identify relationship between l (or ml) and cm³\n}    26          495046
# 7            \\text{Students are able to identify relationship between l (or ml) and cm³\n}    26          495049
# 8            \\text{Students are able to identify relationship between l (or ml) and cm³\n}    26          495050
# 9  \\text{Students are able to write down the notation and representations of fractions \n}    39          473272
# 10 \\text{Students are able to write down the notation and representations of fractions \n}    39          473270
# 11 \\text{Students are able to write down the notation and representations of fractions \n}    39          473269
# 12 \\text{Students are able to write down the notation and representations of fractions \n}    39          473262
# 13 \\text{Students are able to write down the notation and representations of fractions \n}    39          473261
# 14 \\text{Students are able to write down the notation and representations of fractions \n}    39          465453
# 15 \\text{Students are able to write down the notation and representations of fractions \n}    39          465452
```

Comment: Hi Parfait, in fact this table is based on a .bson file. Your solution works perfectly fine, but unfortunately I get an error message, once the linkedSourceList changes its format (more than one row) or gets simply NULL. I have updated the dput output. Just out of curiosity: The final_df is still a list, right ?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

This was kind of challenging, but it works on your new list.

```
library(tidyverse)

li %>% 
  map(enframe) %>% 
  `[`(., c("name", "linkedSourceList")) %>% 
  bind_cols() %>% 
  unnest(value1) %>% 
  select(name = "value", exerciseIdList) %>% 
  unnest(exerciseIdList)
```

---

**Old answer**

Here is a pipe based approach starting from your original list `li`:

```
library(tidyverse)

li %>%
  pluck("linkedSourceList") %>%           # get list element called linkedSourceList
  map("exerciseIdList") %>%               # extract elements called "exerciseIdList
  flatten %>%                             # remove hierarchy level
  set_names(li[["name"]]) %>%             # set_names of sub-list
  enframe(value = "excerciseIdList") %>%  # put list in a tibble with a list-column
  unnest(excerciseIdList)                 # unnest list-column
```

Comment: Thank you Tim ! This works fine in the dput, but whenever I apply it on the underlying df with 2011 rows, I retrieve an error message, maybe due to the fact that the list element called linkedSourceList is sometimes NULL, meaning does not store any information. I have read through the purrr documentation and I am struggling to understand the set_names function. Thank you once again, Tim!

Comment: Hi Tim, I have updated the dput output in my question. I think that it is not so much about the null values in the linkedSourceList, but also about the fact that there can be more than one row of exerciseIds.

Comment: I will give it a look later!

Comment: Hi Tim, it works perfectly, but applying it to the whole set of 2011 rows I am getting an error message `Error: Argument 1182 can't be converted from list to numeric`. My understanding is that this is caused by various data types. In fact, li$name looks like this `structure(list(name = c("\\text{History}", 
"evaluation")`. In the majority of cases the name is also a list. But sometimes not. Row1182 actually has this kind of character string as a name. However there are rows, who also have this character string and no error message gets returned :( Anyway. Thank you very much for your help !!!

Comment: Is it possible that you include row number 1182 in your dput?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201233/discussion-between-user12121022-and-timteafan).