# How can I efficiently loop trough a list containing vectors of different length

Tags: r, performance

I have a list containing vectors of different length which I need to loop trough efficently. As an example here I want to use the print function on each element. However as I will encounter this problem repeatedly, I would like to find an efficient way to do so.

```
list <- list(1, c(1:4), c(3:10))

for (i in seq_along(list)) {
  for(j in seq_along(list[[i]])){
    print(list[[i]][j])
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Some interesting ideas here that might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58474376/print-out-items-from-a-list-in-r-with-different-nested-levels

Comment: `mylist <- list(1, c(1:4), c(3:10)); print(unlist(mylist))`

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is with your code. It doesn't error, and it does exactly what you tell it to: for each of `1`, `1:4`, and `3:10`, iterate over *those* values (i.e., second pass would then iterate over `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`) and print them. In this case since the second-level objects are simple vectors, the inner loop works along individual values, so effectively this becomes `print(1)`, `print(1)`, `print(2)`, `print(3)`, `print(4)`, `print(3)`, `print(4)`, ..., `print(10)`. This is as you coded it. What do you *expect* to happen given this double loop?

Comment: For a list of vectors, which is the case in the question, one `for` loop will do:  `for(x in list) print(x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are interested in efficiency, I've added a benchmarking example to evaluate (1) your approach (2) the approach propose by @Sotos (3) an approach iterating through the list elements (vectors) using lapply and (4) an approach iterating through the list elements (elements of vectors) using lapply and sapply:

```
list2examine <- list(1, c(1:4), c(3:10))

    benchmark("original"= {
  for (i in seq_along(list2examine)) {
    for(j in seq_along(list2examine[[i]])){
      print(list2examine[[i]][j])
    }
  }
}, "Sotos" = {rapply(list2examine, print)},
"lapply" = {lapply(list2examine, function(x) {print(x)} )},
"lapplySapply" = {lapply(list2examine, function(x) { sapply(x, function(i) {print(i)} ) })},
"ismirsehregal" = { print(unlist(list2examine))},

replications=1000,
columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed",
            "relative", "user.self", "sys.self"))

           test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
5 ismirsehregal         1000    0.08    1.000      0.07     0.02
3        lapply         1000    0.11    1.375      0.11     0.00
4  lapplySapply         1000    0.34    4.250      0.36     0.00
1      original         1000    2.80   35.000      2.81     0.07
2         Sotos         1000    0.14    1.750      0.17     0.00
```

As you can see your approach is the slowest ("elapsed") which you've already expected. lapplySapply is slower than rapply, I'll guess that has to do something with the fact that rapply is a recursive function. If you want to read further on benchmarking or how to interpret the result of the function I recommend the article https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/05/5-ways-to-measure-running-time-of-r-code/.

Note that I've changed the name of your list because variable name should not be the same as built-in functions of r.

Also, have in mind that however, these functions are all printing the entry in the list, they differ in the form of iteration.

Comment: Thanks! Could you also add the suggestion by @ismirsehregal?

Answer (score 3):

Try `rapply`, i.e.

```
rapply(list, print)
#[1] 1
#[1] 1 2 3 4
#[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
# [1]  1  1  2  3  4  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```